# Access Nested Fragment Embedded as <Fragment>

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working with an application that has some Fragments containing `<Fragment>` tags.  To date these nested fragments do their own thing and there really is not any interaction between them and the parent fragment.

We are now facing a situation where the parent fragment needs to pass data to the nested fragment.  For simplicity let's consider the data to be a String to be displayed in a TextView.

We can used `findViewById` to reach down into the nested fragment, grab the TextView, and modify it accordingly.  This however does not seem like a good design because the parent is poking around at the internals of the child fragment, which it shouldn't know about and may be changed.  The data may also not be going directly in a child view like in this example.  In other environments we would place a setter/getter method on the child fragment to pass in the text.

The issue we then run into is the `findViewById` can't return the fragment so we can call the method.  How do we get a reference to a nested fragment, embedded with the `<Fragment>` tag from the parent?

Comment: You mean you have no references in the child fragment in the code, its just there in the layout?

Comment: @TharakaDevinda yes, that is correct